# Auto-correct XML indentation in Geany

Tags: xml, editor, indentation, geany

My problem is auto-formatting/indenting XML in Geany, when XML is not properly indented or has no indentation at all.

As I see no Geany plugins for this purpose, I am thinking about using a custom command through **Edit > Format > Send Selection To**. I have tried to use **xmllint --format** for this without success, as it seems like Geany passes it a string, but **xmllint** expects a file.

- Are there other tools for auto-indenting XML through custom Geany commands?
- Is there another way than custom command to achieve this?

Comment: `xmllint`, like so many other programs, would have accepted text from _stdin_ perfectly well, if you had tried passing it via the standard input specifier `-` instead of a filename.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Found a solution. To achieve Xml indentation auto-correction in Geany (Mint/Ubuntu):

1. Install **xmlindent** CLI tool:

   $ sudo apt-get install xmlindent
2. In Geany, at **Edit > Format > Send selection To > Set Custom Commands** add a command:

   xmlindent -i 4 -f

This indents lines by 4 spaces and forces newlines on elements without children.

Comment: If this solved your problem, as it solved mine, please accept your own answer. This way, the question will not appear as open.

Comment: Readers please note that this wasn't strictly necessary as `xmllint` accepts _stdin_ just fine, as I've outlined in a comment on the OP.

Answer (score 8):

The is also the (XML) [pretty printer plugin](http://plugins.geany.org/pretty-printer.html) avaialble redoing indention of an xml document and some more function.

Comment: For Ubuntu (and possibly Debian and other Debian-based distros): `sudo apt install geany-plugin-prettyprinter`. It then appears in the Tools menu as "PrettyPrinter XML".

Comment: To configure the pretty printer plugin go to `Edit` -> `Plugin Preferences` -> `XML PrettyPrinter` (e.g. you can change default indent from 2 spaces to 4 spaces).